# Как исправить ошибку "нет ограничения уникальности, соответствующего данным ключам"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

После запуска этого кода в postgresql

```
Create table Goods(
Code_goods int Primary key not null,
Name_goods varchar(60),
Unit varchar(15),
Date_of_manufacture date,
Price money);
Create table Workers(
Code_workers int not null,
FIO_workers varchar(60),
Addres_workers varchar(160),
Telephon char(15));
Create table Pacts(
Number_pacts int Primary key not null,
Code_workers int not null,
Code_goods int not null,
Date_of_manufacture date,
Count float,
Constraint FK Foreign key(Code_workers)
References Workers(Code_workers),
Constraint LQ Foreign key(Code_goods)
References Goods(Code_goods))
```

выдаёт следующую ошибку:

ERROR:  ОШИБКА:  в целевой внешней таблице "workers" нет ограничения уникальности, соответствующего данным ключам
SQL state: 42830

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся в коде и как это можно исправить.

Answer (score -1):

У таблицы `Workers` нет ограничения уникальности на поле `Code_workers`. Добавьте первичный ключ или UNIQUE

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь.